# Query to eliminate duplicates and report nulls

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working SQL Server 2008. I have a table containing data from a handscanner(s).  Table name is ScanData.

```
Barcode  ScanDate                   ScannerId
*******  ********                   *********
A000012  2013-02-19 11:55:02.900    SGH205YXHD
A000015  2013-02-21 11:30:02.767    SGH205YXHD
A000017  2013-02-21 11:29:19.507    SGH205YXHD
A000012  2013-02-19 10:58:02.900    5C7152P0SB
A000015  2013-02-19 10:41:02.400    SGH205YXHD
A000018  2013-02-19 10:25:02.140    5C7152P0SB
```

I have a second table that links Barcodes to Products.  Table name is Barcode.

```
Barcode  ProductID
*******  *********
A000012  CCC3047A-2E85-413F
A000015  2C4CD739-F09D-44D0
A000018  F48C9B37-7B2F-4446
```

I need to join the tables but without duplicate barcode values. Where there are duplicates, the higher TimeStamp should be selected. So the results should look like:

```
Barcode  ScanDate                   ScannerId    ProductID
*******  ********                   *********    *********
A000012  2013-02-19 11:55:02.900    SGH205YXHD   CCC3047A-2E85-413F
A000015  2013-02-21 11:30:02.767    SGH205YXHD   2C4CD739-F09D-44D0
A000017  2013-02-21 11:29:19.507    SGH205YXHD   null
A000018  2013-02-19 10:25:02.140    5C7152P0SB   F48C9B37-7B2F-4446
```

Note that it is very important that the third row be returned with a null value for the ProductID.

I've made attempts using DISTINCT, PARTITION BY and GROUP BY, but the examples I was following for  eliminating the duplicate didn't have the second table joined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0763a/1

```
select 
    ScanData.Barcode, 
    ScanData.ScanDate, 
    ScanData.ScannerId,
    Barcode.ProductID
From
    ScanData
Left Join
    Barcode
on
    ScanData.Barcode = Barcode.Barcode
join 
(
    select 
        Barcode, 
        max(ScanDate) ScanDate 
    from 
        ScanData 
    Group By Barcode
) Latest
On
    Latest.Barcode = ScanData.Barcode and Latest.ScanDate = Scandata.ScanDate
Order By
    Barcode
```

Comment: Thanks for the help AND for showing it in sqlfiddle. Nice tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
;WITH ScanData_CTE AS
  (
  SELECT sd.Barcode, sd.ScanDate, sd.ScannerId, b.ProductID,
    row_number() over (partition BY sd.Barcode ORDER BY sd.ScanDate DESC) AS rn
  FROM ScanData sd
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Barcode b ON sd.Barcode = b.Barcode
  )

SELECT Barcode, ScanDate, ScannerId, ProductID
FROM ScanData_CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

With a common table expression (CTE) you assign a row number for each barcode in descending date sequence.  Then, select only the first row in each barcode group.

Comment: This also worked. How does this compare efficiency-wise to zespri's method?